# How to implement Screen Recording in React Native

Tags: react-native, video, video-capture, audio-recording, screen-capture

I want to implement Video Recording feature in my React Native App .

I tried many libraries also native module but unfortunately it didn't succeeded , it also show the popup of start recording then nothing happens .

Any suggestions please ?